# Redirecting url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

If a cookie exists

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} tuid=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(dt)$ /ddrc.php?tuid=%1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

if a cookie doesnot exist

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !tuid=[^;]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*&go=([^?&]*)\??([^&]*)&*.*$
RewriteRule ^dt$ ${allowed_sites:%1|/dt.gif}?%2 [NE,E=PROCESSED:TRUE]
```

this htaccess file has been written to redirect users who has a cookie and avoid redirecting the rest who does not contain a cookie. It is determined by the value of "tuid", if tuid contains a value then the user redirected if not user is not redirected.

Now i want to redirect the users who does not have a "tuid" value as well, i have been trying this for some time with no luck... can anybody assist me and sought this thing out

Comment: This seems a little complex, why do you want to do the rewriting in .htaccess? The first case does a redirect, not a rewrite, couldn't you do that in PHP?

Comment: thanks....yeah it can be using php.. but the problem is, i need to do the redirecting only through rewriting urls, can anybody help me on this